# How to start powershell in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, powershell

I try to start powershell as an external tool. 
I want it to be run in the console windows of eclipse.

[image: Config]

But it starts with empty console, and when I type and press return, I get:

```
Missing expression after unary opearator ‘-’.

At line:1 char:2
+ – <<<<  Command Set-Location C:\Users\XXX
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Answer (score 0):

You got misplaced quotes in the Arguments section.

```
-NoExit -"Command Set-Location ${project_loc}"
```

Try moving the quote after `Command` switch like so,

```
-NoExit -Command "Set-Location ${project_loc}"
```

Comment: In this case, there is no error, but no response from powershell as well. No start up or location info. No response to commands.

Comment: It is the same, except that the powershell startup message is printed to the console.